# How to change a default separator for postgresql arrays?

Tags: postgresql

I want to import csv with Postgres' arrays into a Postgres table.

This is my table:

```
create table dbo.countries (
    id char(2) primary key,
    name text not null,
    elements text[]
    CONSTRAINT const_dbo_countries_unique1 unique (id),
    CONSTRAINT const_dbo_countries_unique2 unique (name)
);
```

and I want to insert into that a csv which looks like this:

```
AC,ac,{xx yy}
```

When I type `copy dbo.mytable FROM '/home/file.csv' delimiter ',' csv;` then the array is read as a one string: `{"xx yy"}`.

How to change a deafault separator for arrays from `,` to  ?

Comment: You would have to create your own array type(https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtype.html). "delimiter  The delimiter character to be used between values in arrays made of this type." I have never done that so this is as far I can go.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot to change array's separator symbol. You can read data to table, and later you can run a update on this table:

```
UPDATE dbo.countries
  SET elements = string_to_array(elements[1], ' ')
 WHERE strpos(elements[1], ' ') > 0;
```